# The NA price of a caplet with payoff

Tags: derivatives, finance-mathematics

Prove the following statement:
The NA price of a caplet with payoff
$$\delta \cdot (L(T;T,T+\delta)-k)^{+} $$
at time $T+\delta$ equals the NA price of a put option with the payoff
$$(1+\delta \cdot k)\cdot( \frac{1}{1+\delta \cdot k}-p(T,T+\delta) )^{+}$$
at time T.

---

My idea is:
I try to start using the definition of NA which is
$$\sum_{I=1}^n c_I p(t,T_i)+ K p(t,T_n).$$
Also, a caplet is derivative with payoff
$$Cpl(T,T+\delta ):= \delta \cdot (L(T;T,T+\delta )-k)^{+} $$ 
at time $T+ \delta .$
A floorlet is an interest rate derivative with payoff
$$\delta \cdot(k- L(T;T,T+\delta ))^{+}$$
at time $T+\delta $

Comment: What is your question actually?

Comment: Prove the above statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuitively, you can think of a caplet as the option to sell at time $T$ a one-period ($\delta$) coupon bond with a predetermined coupon rate $k$ for par (say nominal is 1). With the proceeds of the bond sale, you invest in the money market and at time $T + \delta$ you get $1 + \delta L \left(T, T + \delta\right)$. After repaying the principal of the bond with interest $\delta k$, you have locked in the payoff $\delta \left[L \left(T, T + \delta\right) - k \right]^+$. This is an economic justification.

For the maths justification: with the caplet, you receive at time $T + \delta$ the payoff
\begin{align}
\delta \left[L \left(T, T + \delta\right) - k \right]^+ &=
\left[1 + \delta L \left(T, T + \delta\right) - \left(1 + \delta k\right) \right]^+\\
& = \left[\frac{1}{P \left(T, T + \delta\right)} - \left(1 + \delta k\right) \right]^+
\end{align}
To get the payoff at time $T$, you discount at the relevant Libor rate $L\left(T, T + \delta\right)$, which is known at time $T$: that yields
$
\left[1 - P\left(T, T + \delta\right) \left(1 + \delta k\right)\right]
$ and your formula comes immediately.